# The name 'XForms' does not exist in the current context

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

Getting the title error in `UWP App.xaml.cs` file.

I am sending a message from my UWP app to my main project.

Code:

```
 private void OnPushNotificationReceived(PushNotificationChannel sender, PushNotificationReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            var msg = args.ToastNotification.Content.InnerText;
            XForms.MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, SmartWCM.App.NotificationReceivedKey, msg);
        }
```

ScreenShot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MessagingCenter` should be under the **Xamarin.Forms** namespace and not XForms. I haven't seen any Xamarin.Forms controls/classes under the XForms namespace.

Comment: I saw `XForms` usage on the following youtube video, thanks for your solution, it's working.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=le2lDY22xwM